# How to make a GET request with cookie in request header

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to make a GET request which requires a valid cookie to be present in the request header.

I tried the following:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : USERNAME, 'password' : PASSWORD})
opener.open("SERVER_URL, login_data)
resp = opener.open(ORDER_URL)
print resp.read()
```

It gives me the HTML response of the login page.

Also tried:

```
from requests import session
payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': USERNAME,
    'password': PASSWORD
}

with session() as c:
    c.post(SERVER_URL, data=payload)
    request = c.get(ORDER_URL)
    print request.headers
    print request.text
```

It gives me the HTML response of the login page.

Also tried:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar

cj = CookieJar()
p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
p.add_password(None, SERVER_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(*[urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)])
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response2 = opener.open(ORDER_URL)
print response2.read()
```

But still the HTML response

If I copy the cookie from my browser after login and do the following, then I get the correct response:

```
req = urllib2.Request(ORDER_URL)
req.add_header("Cookie", cookie)
pdb.set_trace()
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

How can I set the cookie correctly using python?

The initial login request is giving the following response header:

```
 CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 
  'x-powered-by': 'Express', 'server': 'nginx/1.4.4', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 
  'date': 'Tue, 09 Dec 2014 10:51:46 GMT', 
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})
```

Comment: It looks like your problem might be authenticating rather than the cookie. If you've authenticated properly then the cookie jar will handle the cookie fine. It might help if you post the response (inc. headers) you get for the initial logon request.

Comment: @ed. THanks for your response. I also feel the same. I have updated the question with the login response  header

Comment: @ed. I think I am not using the correct server URL. Is there a way to find correct URL to login to. The API I want to access is `x.y.z/order_management/new_order_items`. So, I am trying to login to `x.y.z/order_management`, which on browser shows the login page. `x.y.z` is also login page. I tried to use both but not getting HTML

Comment: You could try using firebug (or similar) and watch every HTTP request when you log in via the browser. One of those should be the actual authentication...